# Can't access MongoDB from Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using MeteorJS and I find that whenever I'm trying to access the properties of a MongoDB record, I get the following dump in the console
    `Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot call method 'firstNode' of undefined`
    `at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:2000/packages/spark/spark.js?  14a6d0456c829f0ae6b6b21c3d85c12b51d07167:545:25)`
    `at null._func (http://localhost:2000/packages/spark/spark.js?14a6d0456c829f0ae6b6b21c3d85c12b51d07167:866:13)`
    `at _.extend._compute (http://localhost:2000/packages/deps/deps.js?00c1c175771f1d01cbad3013d682a68610670394:126:14)`
    `at _.extend._recompute (http://localhost:2000/packages/deps/deps.js?00c1c175771f1d01cbad3013d682a68610670394:139:16)`
    `at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:2000/packages/deps/deps.js?00c1c175771f1d01cbad3013d682a68610670394:222:16) logging.js:41`

Here is the code paste http://fpaste.org/7OC2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While meteor is finishing its subscriptions up and fetching data from the server, for a very short amount of time, the collections are empty.

So this query:

```
var result = QoD.findOne({week: Session.get('currentWeek')});
```

Wont have any results yet. You just need to handle this case in case there aren't any results:

```
if(result) Session.set('allResponses', result.responses);
```

Comment: I just tried that, still getting the errors mentioned. Are there other conditions where this occur?

Comment: Is there more of a stack trace? So if you remove that Session.set("allResponses", result.responses) line it works?

Comment: I think it may be because of the version number. I ran it again on Ubuntu where I updated Meteor, and it works now :) How can I run a stack trace in Meteor. It'd be helpful since I still have other problems unsolved.

Comment: It might be the version or a cache thing. You have a stack trace above but its not that descriptive of the source line which is causing the issue, I got an idea of what the problem may be because you knew where the error hit in your fpaste